# Laravel session key is null after put in session

Tags: php, angularjs, session, laravel

I have a wired problem. Im put in session some string/object, and when i want to get it is not there.

This is the code:

```
class CartController extends \BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        return Session::all(); // items is not there
    }

    public function store()
    {
        Session::put('items', Input::get('items'));
    }

}
```

in angular:

```
this.saveItemsToSession = function() {
    $http.post('cart', {
      items: 'test even string'
    });
  };
```

What can cause this problem?

Its seems like Session dont work.
This way is working:

```
session_start();
class CartController extends \BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        return $_SESSION['items'];
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $_SESSION['items'] = Input::get('items');
    }

}
```

Comment: If you put static data in the session, does it work? `Session::put('items', 'test string');`

Comment: no, but if i do this in the HomeController its working

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the route(s) for `cart`?

Comment: I found solution but is very wired, i needed to add session_start in the CartController, why you think is that?

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Does only `Session::put` not work without `session_start` or all the session access in `CartController`?

Comment: Well using `$_SESSION` isn't very pretty. Try the `Session` class again but `return null;` from `store()`

Comment: Do you know where laravel init the session_start() ?

Comment: It's somewhere deep in a Symphony class. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: I dont understand what to do.

Comment: Go back to what you had in the beginning and add `return null;` at the end of the `store` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67009/discussion-between-user4207046-and-lukasgeiter).

Comment: What session driver are you using? `app/config/session.php`

Answer (score 3):

From laravel docs : https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing

> Any routes not placed within the web middleware group will not have
>   access to **sessions** and CSRF protection, so make sure any routes that
>   need these features are placed within the group. Typically, you will
>   place most of your routes within this group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
     //all routes
});
```

Put your all routes inside middleware and your problem will solve.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Session::all()
```

return array of all session variables, while

```
    $_SESSION['items']
```

return session of 'items', and both output are different. To get the

```
    $_SESSION['items']
```

value, Here are a few ways:

```
    Session::all()['items']
```

or

```
    Session::get('items')
```

Answer (score -3):

Are you using sub-domains at all?